# Remove all the numeric characters in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to remove all the numeric characters from a string in SQL, e.g. Från Japan samtal till 0046709757417

I want the output to be Från Japan samtal till

thanks.

Comment: i will get full idea once i solve my prob by this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions204.htm#SQLRF06145

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions205.htm#SQLRF51917

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `translate()` function (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm)):

```
select translate(col, 'a0123456789', 'a')
```

This function replaces the characters is in the first string with the corresponding characters in the second string.  The `'a'` is because of a peculiarity of Oracle.  Oracle treats the empty string (`''`) as `NULL`, and `translate()` returns `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`.  The `'a'` allows the second argument to have a value.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=88ab29f6c5035bd5259f62bf37862956) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I think there's a little problem with that... The `translate(string, text_to_replace, replace_with)` function is picky about the **replace_with**. I notice if you try to execute `translate('18234567', '0123456789', 'a')`, it will return `null` instead of `'aaaaaaaa'`. And if you execute `translate('18234567', '1234567890', 'a')`, it will return `a` instead of `'aaaaaaaa'`. In other words, the order in **replace_with** matters.

Comment: @Sometowngeek . . . I'm not sure what the purpose of your comment is.  The code in the answer removes the digits which is what the OP is asking for.  The code in your comment is not related to this answer.

Comment: I ran a test with your answer against the OP’s sample value and it returned null when it should return `'a'` for every instance of a digit plus an additional `'a'`

Comment: IMHO, it’s very tricky to capture only numbers. Even Oracle’s regex functions don’t always work right :-\

Comment: @Sometowngeek . . . The question is about *removing* digits, not replacing them with `'a'`s.  That's why I'm confused about your comments.  I added a db<>fiddle to show that it does what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Derp.... I apologize for the confusion. My brain is fried and after thinking about it for a while, your answer does work. I was at work, trying to find a way to extract just numbers in PL/SQL and came across this and with my frustration, I mis-read the question and didn't think your answer would solve it.

Comment: I can delete my comments here if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

```
regexp_replace('Från Japan samtal till 0046709757417', '[0-9]', '')
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24449

Comment: Regex operations are relatively slow compared to their non-regex counter parts. Even Oracle says so (see [Regex Whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/focus-areas/application-development/twp-regular-expressions-133133.pdf), Performance Considerations). However, I am not sure if there is any better way of solving the problem in this case.

Comment: @SimonKrenger: thanks, interesting read. That piqued my curiosity and I did a quick test applying the `regexp_replace` and the `translate` solution on 500.000 rows with random values between 50 and 250 characters and numbers. The `regexp_replace` solution was about 40% slower. So it is indeed a very noticeable overhead (I didn't expect it to be that much)